# how can i display other user information in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a  website that the user can look at other users profile but the problem is when the user enter another user profile it show his personal information

this is the urls.py file code

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
]
```

this is the view.py file code

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post = Profile
    template_name = 'website/user_posts.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user)

    def get_username_field(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=user)
```

this is the models.py file

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ålder', default=15, 
    blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user_posts', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

user_posts.html file

```
{{ user.get_full_name }}
{{ user.profile.age }}
{{ view.kwargs.username }}
```

in the template it's show the username but it didnt' show the name and the age.

Comment: i am using 2.1.5 django version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` is always the current logged-in user. Your view uses the Profile model, so you can either access `profile` or `object`.

```
{{ profile.user.get_full_name }}
{{ profile.age }}
```

Note, your `get_username_field` method is never called and does not do anything; you should remove it.

Note also, it's really not a good idea to store `age` as an integer in the database. That means you somehow have to update it every year, as people have a strange habit of getting older... Better to store the date of birth, and have a method to display the age.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `{{ profile.user.get_full_name }}`?

Comment: Thank you for the good information it's realy useful but even after i put the          
       {{ profile.age }} it didn't show the age 
i am using 2.1.5 django version

Answer (score 0):

First of all your get_username_field is of no use.

In your views.py,

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'website/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_content'  
    allow_empty = False  #this will show 404 if the username does not exists

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']) 
        # you can do it in one line now
```

Now to show this in html,

```
{% for user in user_content %}
{{user.get_full_name}}
# rest of your code
{% endfor %}
```

You can also show posts of that particular user in same way as above.

Comment: 'Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']' I get this error